# some redirected output gets printed at the end

Tags: bash

Running some shell scripts that run Python scripts, I get re-ordering of stdout lines when redirecting to tee or a file.

For example, if I run the shell script and get output to my stdout, my output looks like:

```
Line1: Starting X 
Line2: Output of X 
Line3: Starting Y 
Line4: Output of Y
```

But If I run the same script and redirect output to file, or use tee, print statements from the underlying Python script will be printed at the very end of execution.

```
Line1: Output of X
Line2: Output of Y
Line3: Starting X
Line4: Starting Y
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the Python script writes to both stdout and stderr, and you're redirecting only one of them (to a file or through `tee`).

To check what output goes where:

```
./myscript 2>/dev/null    # shows only stdout
./myscript >/dev/null     # shows only stderr
```

To redirect both:

```
./myscript >myfile 2>&1   # both to myfile
./myscript |& tee ...     # both through tee
```